# bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}

Tags: python, mongodb, discord, nextcord

Ive been trying to make a leveling system by following a youtube video and when im done with the code it keeps showing me this error again and again. I made sure that the username and password are correct but i might be silly enough to miss something else. I had whitelist IP address from anywhere to access the db and i host the bot on heroku.

The code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self,message):
        cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<BitterDBAdmin>:<hidden>@bitterbotdb.zwiwd.mongodb.net/BitterBotDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
        lvl_system = cluster["BitterLevelDB"]["Leveling_System"]

        xp_channel = 942567995312582676
        message_xp_range = random.randint(10,35)

        if message.channel.id == xp_channel:
            if not message.author.bot:
                stats = lvl_system.find_one({"id":message.author.id})
                if stats is None:
                    new_user = {"id":message.author.id, "xp": 0}
                    lvl_system.insert_one(new_user)
                else:
                    xp = stats["xp"] + message_xp_range
                    lvl_system.update_one({"id": message.author.id},{"$set":{"xp":xp}})
                    lvl = 0
                    while True:
                        if xp < ((50*(lvl**2))+(50*(lvl-1))):
                            break
                        lvl += 1
                    xp -= ((50*(lvl**2))+(50*(lvl-1)))
                    if xp == 0:
                        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} reached **{lvl}**\n*This feature is not completed.*")
```

The error:

```
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\client.py", line 415, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Bitter\VCS\Test Bot\Modules\Leveling System\codes.py", line 26, in on_message
    stats = lvl_system.find_one({"id":message.author.id})
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1114, in find_one
    for result in cursor.limit(-1):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1159, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1080, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(q)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 971, in __send_message
    response = client._run_operation(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1215, in _run_operation
    return self._retryable_read(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1307, in _retryable_read
    with self._secondaryok_for_server(read_pref, server, session) as (
  File "C:\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1162, in _secondaryok_for_server
    with self._get_socket(server, session) as sock_info:
  File "C:\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1099, in _get_socket
    with server.get_socket(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1371, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket(all_credentials)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1483, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.connect(all_credentials)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1337, in connect
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 814, in check_auth
    self.authenticate(credentials)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 831, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 548, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 469, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram(credentials, sock_info, 'SCRAM-SHA-1')
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 205, in _authenticate_scram
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 719, in command
    return command(self, dbname, spec, secondary_ok,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 158, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 170, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: yes it did thank you

Answer (score 0):

I made a very common mistake while entering my username and password. I should remove "<" and ">" in:

```
cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<BitterDBAdmin>:<hidden>@bitterbotdb.zwiwd.mongodb.net/BitterBotDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
```

Source:
[Mongodb + Atlas: 'bad auth Authentication failed.', code: 8000,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60020381/mongodb-atlas-bad-auth-authentication-failed-code-8000)