# Authentication failed on a previously perfectly running MongoDB server hosted on Mongo Atlas

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

'Authentication failed' error on a previously perfectly running MongoDB server hosted on MongoDB Atlas.

I have an instance of MongoDB running in MongoDB cloud. Everything was fine then all of a sudden I get an 'Authentication failed' error.

The funny thing is that this happened before then I changed my password in MongoDB cloud and it worked. How can I solve this permanently?

I am using MongoDB via mongoose in a NextJS app.

Comment: I think I found a solution form [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66972285/9953550). The solution seems to be to remove numbers from the password and adding  authSource: <The database to use when authenticating>. More about authSource: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options

Comment: i doubt this is true

Comment: @dododo even the adding 'authSource' part?

Comment: authSource is needed as I recall, but password shape should not have meaning

Comment: Yeah, it seems it was a wrongful attribution.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the password used, this will solve the issue. I have encoded my password using the https://www.urlencoder.org/

```js
connection_string = 'mongodb+srv://username:encodedpassword@clustername.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
# I had to remove the db name from the URL to make this work, so you can set the database name below

# Establish a connection to the MongoDB server

data_collection = mongo(collection="name_of_collection", db="database", url=connection_string)

# Query all documents in the collection
result <- Pacientes_collection$find()
```