Authentication error with connection string mongodb
I have this file to test a connection to my MongoDB database:
import { MongoClient } from "./deps.ts";
import { load } from "./deps.ts";

await load({ export: true });

const mongoUri = Deno.env.get("MONGODB_URI");
if (!mongoUri) {
  throw new Error("MONGODB_URI is not defined in the environment variables");
}

const client = new MongoClient();

try {
  console.log("Attempting to connect to MongoDB...");
  await client.connect(mongoUri);
  console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB!");
  
  // Test the connection
  const db = client.database("vitalityVista");
  const collections = await db.listCollections().toArray();
  console.log("Available collections:", collections);

} catch (error) {
  console.error("MongoDB connection error:", error);
  throw error;
} finally {
  await client.close();
} 


And I am getting this error: MongoDB connection error:
Error: MongoError: "Connection failed: MongoError: {\"ok\":0,\"errmsg\":\"bad auth : authentication failed\",\"code\":8000,\"codeName\":\"AtlasError\"}"                                                                          
    at MongoClient.connect (https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.32.0/src/client.ts:46:13)  
    at eventLoopTick (ext:core/01_core.js:175:7)
    at async file:///C:/Users/enman/OneDrive - BYU-Idaho/vitality_vista/backend/test_mongo.ts:15:3
error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: MongoError: "Connection failed: MongoError: {\"ok\":0,\"errmsg\":\"bad auth : authentication failed\",\"code\":8000,\"codeName\":\"AtlasError\"}"
      throw new MongoDriverError(`Connection failed: ${e.message || e}`);
            ^
    at MongoClient.connect (https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.32.0/src/client.ts:46:13)  
    at eventLoopTick (ext:core/01_core.js:175:7)
    at async file:///C:/Users/enman/OneDrive - BYU-Idaho/vitality_vista/backend/test_mongo.ts:15:3

The connection string is correct because I connected to the database using mongosh and had no issues with it, which could be the cause? my password or user do not have special characters as well.

did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66093136/10210069

Maybe this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470 Does your password has any special characters?

Adding authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1 in the connection string did the trick for me.
